# Check if numpy arrays is inside another numpy array and create a mask

Tags: python, numpy

Given the numpy array a

```
a = [[[0 0] [1 0] [2 0]]
     [[0 1] [1 1] [2 1]]
     [[0 2] [1 2] [2 2]]]
```

And the list b

```
b = [[1, 0], [2, 0]]
```

How can I get the mask c

```
c = [[False True True]
     [False False False]
     [False False False]]
```

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the numpy array

Comment: a = np.dstack((np.meshgrid(x, y))), where x = y = [0, 1, 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use numpy broadcast feature to compare each number pair in b with all pairs on b like below

```py
## np.newaxis add a new dimension at that position. missing dimension (i.e 
## dimension with size 1) will repeat to match size of corresponding dimension

a = np.asarray([[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
     [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
     [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]])[:,:,np.newaxis,:]

b = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 0]])[np.newaxis,:,:]

(a == b).all(axis=3).any(axis=2)
```

**Result**

```
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Comment: I know that comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post, but thank you.